# Checking the similarities between 2 texts and in a dataframe of 100 rows (thus more than 2 sentences)

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, levenshtein-distance, sentence-similarity

I have a dataframe of 100 rows and i would like to compare the similarities between the column OriginalTxt and the SummarizedTxt

| OriginalTxt | SummarizedTxt |
| --- | --- |
| Due to the horizontal pusher system, the highest possible operational security is guaranteed. So that the load can be pushed off with the lowest possible friction values, the agroliner pusher trailer has a stainless steel base as standard and the pusher plate is coated with VA sheet steel plates. The side panels are designed to be torsion-resistant so that the seal, particularly with bulk cargo such as rapeseed and grain, is guaranteed to be long-lasting. The standard large volume tailgate effectively increases the loading volume. | The agroliner pusher trailer has a stainless steel base as standard and the pusher plate is coated with VA sheet steel plates . The side panels are designed to be torsion-resistant so that the seal, particularly with bulk cargo such as rapeseed and grain, is guaranteed to be long-lasting . |
| Calf-Tel Pro hutches are designed to allow calves to seek their ideal level of comfort in any of the various micro environments. The hutch has the same size and design as the DELUXE but has a fully opened entrance. Calf-Tec offers the lowest depreciation, longest life. | With calves isolated from each other, there is little or no transfer of disease between calves . Indestructable High Density Polyethylene our hutches are easy to sanitise and move . This results in a system that will not transfer disease from one group to the next . |

So i tried to use different librairies like sentence-similarity 1.0.0 or the Levenhstein one but it works for 2 sentences at the time but not as a function for the whole dataframe :

`compare('Head Wrap The Head Wrap is innovative in its ability to provide uninterrupted therapy throughout a variety of therapies. It offers an innovative, non-invasive method of controlling core body temperature. Plus, it is a great alternative to ice or ice packs since its versatile design provides therapy in a wide variety of clinical situations. Benefits Unique design allows for easy access to the head and neck area Head cooling is a useful adjunct treatment to whole body hypothermia in regulating temperature Helps maintain normothermia Features One size fits most Adjustable Velcro® Straps Soft material for patient comfort Specifications Model No. - Sizes: 600 - One size fits most','The Head Wrap is an innovative non-invasive method of controlling core body temperature. Unique design allows for easy access to the head and neck area. Helps maintain normothermia in regulating temperature and is a useful adjunct to whole body hypothermia treatment.')`

It works when comparing one sentence to another  `0.6137419245698322`

I tried this:  `compare(df.IDPTexteEn, df.Résumé)`

and this:

```
def compare_row_wise(row):
    return compare(row['summaries'], row['abstracts'])

df.apply(compare_row_wise, axis=1)
```

but it doesn't works and gives me this :

`compare() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string_j'`

Thank you in advance if you guys have any idea to help ^^"

Comment: What is `compare()`? Please show your imports so that we cna understand what you're actually doing

Comment: pip install pysimilar

Comment: from pysimilar import compare
compare('very light indeed', 'how fast is light')